# When using Fetch API I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: packages.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, promise, fetch

I am using the **[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)** to fetch some data from an API's endpoint.

**I am getting this error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: package.map is not a function
```

I made some research & it seems that the error occurs because the response is a object instead of an array.

**This is a code sample:**

```
 const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';

 const fetchPromise = fetch(url);

 fetchPromise.then(response => {

   return response.json();

 }).then(people => {

   // checks response value type
   console.log(typeof people);

   const names = people.map(person => person.name).join('\n');
 });
```

You can find my [sample code here](https://jsfiddle.net/fcypLt4r/2/).

Comment: Can you check with your response from that url?

Comment: Correct, that response is an object not an array. It's unclear what you expected map would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is the thing you are trying to do ,

```
var url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';

 var fetchPromise = fetch(url);

 fetchPromise.then(response => {

   return response.json();

 }).then(people => {
     console.log("people" , people.data);
   // checks response value type
   console.log(typeof people);
//here in the response of the people , it was object , but the people.data is array and on which you can use .map() .
   const names = people.data.map(person => person.first_name + " " + person.last_name).join('\n');
   console.log("names ==.>" , names);
 });
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! thanks! Do you mind adding an explanation on why does it works? Like that, everybody looking for the same problem will understand & so do I :)

Comment: I was going to, don't worry. I was just waiting for 3 minutes restriction that the system set on my vote ;)

Comment: Thank you so much . @ManuelAbascal . In the above answer , do you need any explanation then you can ask to me anytime .

Comment: Yes, why my solution wasn't working? Can you edit the answer to showcase the explanation?

Comment: Sorry for late response . Edited the answer @ManuelAbascal . Why you have removed the acceptance sign ? Wasn't it working ?

Comment: I was waiting for an explanation. I thought you were not giving it since it provided, I added back. It's important when providing a working answer to also provide the explanation for other fellow developers can understand.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting me . @ManuelAbascal . Will take care of it onwards . Sorry for it .

Answer (score 3):

Your API endpoint `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2` is returning an object you can use `map` only with arrays. I guess you want to use data field of returned object that is an array of person objects.

```
const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';

 const fetchPromise = fetch(url);

 fetchPromise.then(response => {

   return response.json();

 }).then(people => {

   // checks response value type
   console.log(typeof people);

   const names = people.data.map(person => person.first_name).join('\n');
 });
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because of the explanation.